# What is the maxium number of tables in a H2 database?

Tags: h2

What is the maxium number of tables in a H2 database? I could not find any info in the documentation. Of course I could test it but I was wondering whether there is an official/documented upper limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As such there is no upper limit to the number of tables which you can create in a H2 database.

You can refer **[Limits and Limitations](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations)**

> There is no limit for the following entities, except the memory and
>   storage capacity: maximum identifier length (table name, column name,
>   and so on); maximum number of tables, columns, indexes, triggers, and
>   other database objects; maximum statement length, number of parameters
>   per statement, tables per statement, expressions in order by, group
>   by, having, and so on; maximum rows per query; maximum columns per
>   table, columns per index, indexes per table, lob columns per table,
>   and so on; maximum row length, index row length, select row length;
>   maximum length of a varchar column, decimal column, literal in a
>   statement.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html states:

There is no limit for the following entities, except the memory and storage capacity: maximum identifier length (table name, column name, and so on); 
**maximum number of tables**, columns, indexes, triggers, and other database objects; maximum statement length, number of parameters per statement, tables per statement, expressions in order by, group by, having, and so on; maximum rows per query; maximum columns per table, columns per index, indexes per table, lob columns per table, and so on; maximum row length, index row length, select row length; maximum length of a varchar column, decimal column, literal in a statement.